# How to download Android SDK data without the manager (because it freezes)

Tags: android

When I try to run the `SDK Setup.exe` in my sdk folder, it will open up fine. I then get an error for fetching so I change the https to http and proceed to (try) and download. It usually hangs around 2% and it won't go past 10% so far, I've tried to restart it at least 10 times.

Is there anyway I can ignore this program and just download the files from my browser somewhere? Is there a way to make this program work properly?

The Eclipse plugin also does the same thing, however I got to around 50% progress with it. Why is this happening?

Comment: Hmm.. are you sure it's not your internet connection? Because the Eclipse plugin runs SDK Setup.exe to download the APIs, so it shouldn't be any different.

Comment: I'm browsing the internet just fine. I've played online games such as Warcraft and I've been chatting on AIM. I don't think I have an internet issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the manager to work in windows by restarting my computer in Safe Mode With Networking.  Doing that allowed me to successfully install things through the manager in eclipse.